# Cannot get data out of the dataprovider in a flex application

Tags: flash, apache-flex, list, builder, itemrenderer

I am building an app for a website that will filter through the shops carrying some products/brands and show the results in a List component. I got all the way up to loading the data, putting brands/countries/cities in comboboxes so a user can filter in which country and city he wants to look and for which brand. No problem till now. My problem is that while the dataprovider works as it should when hardcoding some values to the labels that i use for the item renderer of each entry, i cannot get the real data from the data provider.. you will see in the code below, that in the VGroup component (which i use for each shop in the list) there are 4 labels, where 3 of them are hard coded, just to see it works. One of the labels though is trying to get the real data from the xml file and thats where i stop. In all the tutorials i ve seen (and documentation too) everybody just hits "data.XYZ" where XYZ is the name of the attribute or node to get. Doing the same in my case just returns an error of "1120: Access of undefined property data.". What am i doing wrong? Its been a couple of hours i am iterating over hundreds of examples for flex, both new and old versions and i cant find out what to do. Its really nerve breaking to stick to this last small thing when all the rest are in! Have a look at the code and let me know if i did something the wrong way or i missed something! posting the code below. There is also an xml file but its loaded correctly and the different xmlLists DO have the correct nodes stored, so i do not think it needs to be posted, unless you think otherwise. The xml nodes for each shop are "title", "tel","mail","city" and i am stuck trying to get the title. The function that matters the most is the filterShops one and then of course the whole list and itemrenderer block.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               width="815" height="578" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="sendData()">

    <fx:Style source="styles.css"/>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:HTTPService id="shopsService" url="data/places.xml"     result="shopsService_return(event)" resultFormat="e4x"/>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.collections.XMLListCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;

            private var placesXML:XMLList;

            [Bindable] private var countriesList:XMLListCollection;
            [Bindable] private var brandsList:XMLListCollection;
            [Bindable] private var citiesList:XMLListCollection;
            [Bindable] private var shopsList:XMLListCollection;
            [Bindable] public var gridList:XMLListCollection;

            private var selectedCountry:int = 0;
            private var selectedCountryId:int = 0;
            private var selectedBrand:int = 0;
            private var selectedCity:int = 0;
            private var selectedBrandId:int = 0;
            private var selectedCityId:int = 0;

            private function sendData():void {
                shopsService.send();
            }

            private function shopsService_return(event:ResultEvent):void {
                placesXML = XMLList(event.result);
                brandsList = new XMLListCollection(placesXML.brands.brand);
                citiesList = new     XMLListCollection(placesXML.countries.country[0].cities.city);
                shopsList = new XMLListCollection(placesXML.shops.shop);
                gridList = new XMLListCollection();
            }

            private function onBrandboxChange(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
                selectedBrand = event.target.selectedIndex;
                selectedBrandId = placesXML.brands.brand[selectedBrand].attribute("id");
                filterShops(selectedCountryId.toString(),selectedBrandId.toString(),selectedCityId.toString());
            }

            private function onCityboxChange(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
                selectedCity = event.target.selectedIndex;
                selectedCityId = placesXML.countries.country[selectedCountry].cities.city[selectedCity].attribute("id");
                filterShops(selectedCountryId.toString(),selectedBrandId.toString(),selectedCityId.toString());
            }

            private function englandClick(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                citiesList = new XMLListCollection(placesXML.countries.country[0].cities.city);
                selectedCountry = 0;
                selectedCountryId = 1;
            }

            private function scotlandClick(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                citiesList = new XMLListCollection(placesXML.countries.country[1].cities.city);
                selectedCountry = 1;
                selectedCountryId = 2;
            }

            private function filterShops(countryId:String,brandId:String,cityId:String):void {
                var xmlCountryId:String;
                var indexOfBrandId:int;
                var xmlCityId:String;
                //outputLabel.text = countryId+"-"+brandId+"-"+cityId;

                for (var i:int = 0; i < shopsList.length; i++) {
                    xmlCountryId = shopsList[i].attribute("country");
                    xmlCityId = shopsList[i].attribute("city");

                    if (xmlCountryId == countryId && xmlCityId == cityId) {
                        indexOfBrandId = shopsList[i].attribute("brands").toString().split(",").indexOf(brandId);
                        if (indexOfBrandId > -1) gridList.addItem(shopsList[i]);
                    }
                    outputLabel.text = shopsList[0].title;
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:List id="outputWindow" x="10" y="230" width="795" height="338" borderVisible="false"
        dataProvider="{gridList}">
        <s:layout>
            <s:TileLayout
            requestedColumnCount="4"
            requestedRowCount="2"
            horizontalGap="2"
            verticalGap="2"/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:itemRenderer>
            <fx:Component>
                <s:VGroup width="180" height="90">
                    <s:Label styleName="item-title" text="{data.title}" />
                    <s:Label color="#868686" fontFamily="pfHighwayRegular" fontSize="12" paddingBottom="-2"
                         paddingTop="-2" styleName="item-text" text="Tel: 0120 230 3777"/>
                    <s:Label styleName="item-text" text="Mail: info@2012ltd.co.uk"/>
                    <s:Label styleName="item-link" text="Web: www.2012ltd.co.uk"/>
                </s:VGroup>
            </fx:Component>
        </s:itemRenderer>
    </s:List>
    <s:Button x="6" y="8" label="England" click="englandClick(event)"/>
    <s:Button x="125" y="8" label="Scotland" click="scotlandClick(event)" />
    <s:Button x="261" y="10" label="Wales"/>
    <s:Button x="400" y="10" label="Ireland"/>
    <s:ComboBox x="505" y="56" id="brandBox" dataProvider="{brandsList}" change="onBrandboxChange(event)" />
    <s:ComboBox x="659" y="56" id="cityBox" dataProvider="{citiesList}" change="onCityboxChange(event)" />
    <s:Label id="outputLabel" x="10" y="119" text="Label"/>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Hiya user, this is the program speaking :).  So take your component out of being an inline definition and define it in another file, that will make this slightly less confusing, when you do so add a implements to to the VGroup and implement IDropInListItemRenderer and IDataRenderer.  This means you'll have a data property and a listData property within the renderer, the data will have one element of the list assigned to it for each renderer used (or re-used) the listData will have information about the main list and the index of the data in the dataProvider etc.

Comment: Two other things to note, I don't see where gridList is populated with anything? Also if you're using attributes within XML instead of nodes you need to use the @ symbol before the attribute name.

Comment: I will try that way too. gridList is populated in the filterShops function using addItem. It does fill the list cause else, i would not see anything populating the List component :). The attributes are just the id's, i will not need them as the real data is in nodes. will report back once i try doing it this way.

Comment: i just solved it using your method. how can i choose a comment though as the coorect answer? Maybe you need to  make it into an answer? Sorry for being noob, first time asking in stack overflow! :D

Comment: you can up-vote the comment, but I posted it as an answer as well (one or the other would be fair, they give 15 points for an answer I think and 10 for an upvote, not sure if that applies to comments too)  No worries though really I just come here to blow off steam and see other people have problems too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So take your component out of being an inline definition and define it in another file, that will make this slightly less confusing, when you do so add a implements to to the VGroup and implement IDropInListItemRenderer and IDataRenderer. This means you'll have a data property and a listData property within the renderer, the data will have one element of the list assigned to it for each renderer used (or re-used) the listData will have information about the main list and the index of the data in the dataProvider etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reference your List component in your itemRenderer. In fact, this may be true for any inline item renderer.  Try this:

```
<s:Label styleName="item-title" text="{parentDocument.data.title}" />
```

or this:

```
<s:Label styleName="item-title" text="{outerDocument.data.title}" />
```

Comment: I just tried the parentDocument way and while it will not give me an error anymore, it will not show any text too (in the label). I need to find out if everything else is ok since it is not giving me any errors. Using outerDocument still gives me errors though

Comment: parentDocument refers to the MXML file that the Component is used in, within the context shown here that would be "this" with respect to the application, you don't want the application's data, you want the data for that item renderer... I'm not so sure about outerDocument's meaning, definitely take the path of implementing the two interfaces though you'll thank me down the line when it turns out you need more contextual information about the renderer (it comes up often enough that I usually just do this when I'm implementing a renderer now)